# Partial derivative notation: $\left.\frac{\partial \cdot}{\partial\cdot} \right|_{u=T}$

Tags: notation, derivatives

Let $\displaystyle \ \ B(t,T):=\int_t^T f(t,s)ds$, where $f(.,.)$ is a stochastic process whose solution we don't know.

My lecture slides make the claim that:

$$f(t,T) = \frac{\partial B(t,u)}{\partial u} \Bigg|_{u=T}$$

My **first question** is, what's the notation $\frac{\partial .}{\partial.} \Bigg|_{u=T}$?

My **second question** is what is this notation?

$$\frac{\partial B(t,T)}{\partial T} \Bigg|_{T\searrow t}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is the value of the derivative in $u=T$ (just substitution).

The second is *maybe* the limit where $T$ tends monotonously to $t$.

Comment: For the first question, why couldn't he have done $\frac{\partial B(t,T)}{\partial T}$, instead of using $u$ and then substituting in $T$ afterwards?

Comment: The short answer is: because $T$ is the function argument, that is,  considered constant in the RHS; but you can only differentiate w.r.t. independent variable. For example, put you want $f(t,5)$. The RHS becomes meaningless.